# Pointer cast while pass by referance

Tags: c++

Look at my code, I can cast `GoodMan` pointer to a `Man` pointer and pass in to `AddMan` function using two steps. But when I uses one step to do that, It doesn't work. Instead, It needs to cast to the `Man` **pointer reference explicitly** not only to the `Man` pointer. What is the reason behind this?

```
    class Man{
    };

    class GoodMan: public Man
    {
    };

    void AddMan(Man*& man){};

    int main()
    {
        GoodMan* good_man = new GoodMan() ;

        //This works
        Man* pMan2 = (Man*)good_man;    
        AddMan(pMan2);

        //So I think this should work, But doesn't work
        AddMan((Man*)good_man);

        //But this works
        AddMan((Man*&)good_man);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: MingW TDM GCC clearly indicate the problem in compilation error, main.cpp:26:26: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Man*&' from an rvalue of type 'Man*'
     AddMan((Man*)good_man);

Comment: Why do you need to pass a pointer by reference ? Pass by value !

Comment: @vincent. This is just a sample to show the situation.

Comment: What I mean is: the whole point of passing by reference is that you can modify the original value. Do you have any other reason to do that ? Of course, C++ doesn't let you modify a GoodMan * variable as if it was a Man* variable. So what you are trying to achieve cannot work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AddMan((Man*&)good_man);` causes undefined behaviour.   This is aliasing a `GoodMan *` as a `Man *` which is not permitted. It is a `reinterpret_cast`.

Although `GoodMan` is derived from `Man` , `GoodMan *` is not "derived" from `Man *`, they are incompatible types.

Example:

```
AddMan(static_cast<Man*&>(good_man));   // error: invalid static_cast

AddMan(reinterpret_cast<Man*&>(good_man));   // no error, but runtime UB
```

To help "sniff out" this problem, think about the `void AddMan(Man*& man);` function.  It accepts a reference to `Man *`. It has to be called with a variable that is actually a `Man *`. The reference has to bind to a `Man *` specifically. In your original code, what has the reference bound to?  `good_man` is not a `Man *`.

Comment: You drag me to totally different point. So if I fallow the C++ standards, I should not use `AddMan((Man*&)good_man)` method?

Comment: And somewhat related: the cast in `Man* pMan2 = (Man*)good_man;` is unnecessary and should not be used in order to prevent accidentally hiding an invalid conversion.

Comment: That's right. In fact, never using C-style casts will help you avoid pitfalls. Invalid `static_cast`s will usually give an error (but not always).

Comment: @MichaelBurr i think the point of that is to illustrate symmetry  between that line, and the following attempt of passing `(Man *)good_man` to the function

Comment: So the only correct way to do this is `Man* pMan2 = (Man*)good_man;    
AddMan(pMan2);`. am I right?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya yes, but it'd be better to remove the cast. (As we have been discussing, casts can suppress a compiler error that you might have otherwise seen, so it's best to not use them unless as a last resort).

Answer (score 9):

C++ doesn't allow binding rvalues (bacically temporaries) such s `(Man*)good_man` to non-const lvalue references such as `Man*&`. In your code, `pMan2` is an lvalue, so this can bind to the non-const reference parameter of `AddMan`. But `(Man*)good_man` is an rvalue. This is the cause of the error.

If you change the signature of `AddMan` to take a const lvalue reference, your code would compile.

```
void AddMan(Man* const& man){};
```

Of course, this doesn't allow you to change the pointer passed as argument. On the other hand, your solution, to cast to lvalue reference, "works" as far as making the code compile. But you have to ask yourself what it would mean to modify the pointer inside of the `AddMan` function.

```
AddMan((Man*&)good_man); // "works" by pretending everything is OK. It isn't.
```

Comment: So you mean `(Man*&)good_man` not a rvalue ?. Could you please explain a little further how does `(Man*&)good_man` works there?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya `(Man*&)good_man` is an lvalue reference to  a pointer to `Man`. That is what the function expects. You are fooling the compiler into thinking it is getting a reference to a `Man*` when in fact you are referring to a `GoodMan*`. This doesn't really "work". It just compiles.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `(Man*)good_man` is an **r-value** (i.e. a temporary) while `(Man*&)good_man` and `pMan2` are **l-values**.

When binding a reference:

1. **l-value reference** `Man&` = **l-value**
2. **r-value reference** `Man&&` = **r-value**
3. **const l-value reference** `const Man&` = any type of reference
4. **const r-value reference** `const Man&&` = **const and non-const r-value**

What you have as the function parameter is a **l-value** reference, which therefore can only bind to an **l-value**.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: There's a tricky case 5. if `T` is a dependent template parameter then `T&&` can bind to non-const rvalues and lvalues.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Are you referring to reference collapsing?

Comment: That's related but we were enumerating which types of expression can bind

Answer (score 0):

`(Man*)good_man` is an `rvalue` and hence can't bind to a reference of `Man*`. `(Man*&)good_man` on the other hand has already been casted to a compatible type and works fine. Note that if you change the signature of `AddMan` to take a const reference, all your examples will work fine.